# How to calculate Bitmap pixel size in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, pixel

I loaded a 640 x 480 (in px) jpg image from res using Bitmap.

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bmp);
```

But I found:

- the value of bitmap.getWitdh() is 1280;
- the value of bitmap.getHeight() is 960;
- the value of bitmap.getRowBytes() is 2560;

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your mobile phone. Since android supports multiple screens, in order to allow bitmap to scale in the same way across different screens the original bitmap is stored in order to meet the density of your screen. Given the value you posted seems that your mobile has an xdpi screen. Probably getHeight() and getWidth would have you return  480 and 640 if you mobile had been an mdpi. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more info

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you do not specify any `BitmapFactory.Options`, in particular [`inTargetDensity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inTargetDensity) field. Try using [`decodeResource(Resources, resId, BitmapFactory.Options)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) method instead.

Comment: you can set the options to `val options = BitmapFactory.Options().apply { inScaled = false }`, to prevent scaling.